# Get a list of network manager network connections with Bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, network-manager, nmcli

I want to get a list of Ethernet and wireless connections from the terminal. Those connections are listed in NetworkManager's GUI and include info like the connection's SSID.

[image: NetworkManager GUI with connections]

The next step is to delete unwanted connections.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All NetworkManager connections are located in: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

So you can easily use `ls` to get a list of them:

```
ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

then remove the one you want:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/some-connection
```

You can also use [`nmcli`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html#connection) tool, which is a better idea:

To get a list of connections:

```
nmcli connection
```

To get informations about a connection:

```
nmcli connection show connection-name
```

You can pip it to `grep` to look for specific info:

```
nmcli connection show connection-name | grep ipv4.dns
```

To modify a connection:

```
nmcli connection modify connection-name config-name new-alue
```

Example:

```
nmcli connection modify HomeNetwork ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8
```

To delete a connection

```
nmcli connection delete connection-name
```

Comment: `nmcli con` is equivalent to `nmcli connection`, which makes for more concise commands.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun for even more brevity,  `nmcli c` also works. I believe it is some form of auto completion.